# Android kernel for emulator

Tags: android

when I build the kernel from aosp using the command
BUILD_INITRAMFS=1 BUILD_CONFIG_FRAGMENTS=common-modules/virtual-device/goldfish_defconfig.fragment BUILD_CONFIG=common-modules/virtual-device/build.config.virtual_device.x86_64 build/build.sh
The file goldfish_defconfig.fragment contains only one line
CONFIG_BT_HCIBTUSB=m
After that i try to run the emulator with prebuilt kernel it works. When I try using my built kernel it displays the following
kernel too old to load a ramdisk.
How to solve the problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I started the emulator with -show-kernel parameter I got disagrees about version of symbol module_layout so I knew that the problem is kernel version. I was using the android-12.1.0_r8. I determined the kernel version from the prebuilts kernels with the command file kernel-5.10 and got version 5.10.66. Then I found that I need the branch common-android12-5.10-2021-11 so I executed

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/manifest -b common-android12-5.10-2021-11
```

Then I built the kernel with commands

```
BUILD_CONFIG=common/build.config.gki.x86_64 build/build.sh
BUILD_CONFIG=common-modules/virtual-device/build.config.virtual_device.x86_64 build/build.sh
```

Using [android build instructions](https://www.codeinsideout.com/blog/android/build-aosp/#aosp-emulator) I modified the device/generic/goldfish/x86_64-kernel.mk file and successfully built android. I built without any source code modifications and started
it successfully inside emulator modifications